I don't understand why the result of the last statement is 6
let x = 2;;

let x = 3
in let y = x +1
    in x + 1;;

let x = 3 and y = x + 1 
in x + y;;

The results are ordered respectively to each expression:
val x : int = 2

- : int = 7

- : int = 6

Can you help me understand why the last expression equals 6, it's hard for me to understand it.
I run this code in tryOCamlpro.

The first one is self-explanatory.
The second one should warn you that y is unused. x is 3, so x + 1 is 4. Your observed result of 7 suggests that the code you've shown us is not actually what you evaluated.
For the third, let's try something a bit different:
# let x = 3 and y = x + 1 
in (x, y);;
- : int * int = (3, 3)

Huh. Let's fire up a clean interpreter environment and try that:
# let x = 3 and y = x + 1 in (x, y);;
Error: Unbound value x

From this we can see that the definition of y wasn't using the x defined as 3 but rather the previous definition of x as 2.
You likely wanted:
# let x = 3 in 
  let y = x + 1 in 
  x + y;;
- : int = 7

When you use let <pattern> = <expr> and <pattern> = <expr> or let <pattern> = <expr> and <pattern> = <expr> in <expr> the definitions are independent of one another. As a result, this is much less common than let <pattern> = <expr> let <pattern> = <expr> or let <pattern> = <expr> let <pattern> = <expr> in <expr>
If we modify this construct to let rec <pattern> = <expr> and <pattern> = <expr> or let rec <pattern> = <expr> and <pattern> = <expr> in <expr> we can define mutually recursive functions. This is not common.

thank you for the explanation, about the second case which returned 7 as i said i tried it in tryOCamlpro which is online compiler.

If you're going to really explore OCaml I suggest installing it on your computer, along with utop.

let rec x = 3 and y = x + 1 in … would also have worked, right?

let rec x = 3 and y = x + 1 in is not a valid recursive definition.

The toplevel interpreter makes it very easy to test these kinds of things. When in doubt, try it.
